# Adding bleed around clipping mask irregular shap

Tags: print-design, mask, bleed

I have an irregular shape that is going to be printed.
The printing requires a 0.125" bleed.

The shape is created through a clipping mask to isolate the object from a background.
How do I add a bleed around this shape so the design is not cut off?

[image]

Comment: What software are you using?

Comment: @BillyKerr Illustrator

Comment: Probably not much you can do in illustrator to be honest.  A potential solution might be to use the content aware fill in Photoshop to extend the size of the shoes.